# Android - Where Clause

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm developing an inventory system using Android Studio. the function of my application is user can retrieve details when they search a product.

I want to make an application that can:

**user can search the location, size and quantity of the product at the same time by using product's code as an input**

for example, when user key in the product's code, the search result would display location, quantity, and the size.

I have already done with the where clause of product location. for this where clause, my table called "product_info" consists of two columns, which are "product_code" and "product_place"

so I want to create another table called "product_info2" that have two columns of "product_size" and "product_quantity".

but my problem is:

1. how to make the "product_code" as a primary key and a foreign key to the "product_info2" table?
2. how to make the where clause to show these 2 tables at the same time?

here is my coding for "product_info" table. the class called ProductDBHelper.java:

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PRODUCTINFO.DB";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String CREATE_QUERY =
        "CREATE TABLE "+ ProductContract.NewProductInfo.TABLE_PRODUCT+"("+ProductContract.NewProductInfo.PRODUCT_CODE+" TEXT,"+
            ProductContract.NewProductInfo.PRODUCT_PLACE+" TEXT);";

public ProductDbHelper (Context context)
{

    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATIONS", "Database created / opened...");

}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)

{

    db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
    Log.e("DATABASE OPERATIONS", "Table created...");

}

public void addInformations(String code, String place, SQLiteDatabase db)

{
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(ProductContract.NewProductInfo.PRODUCT_CODE, code);
    contentValues.put(ProductContract.NewProductInfo.PRODUCT_PLACE, place);
    db.insert(ProductContract.NewProductInfo.TABLE_PRODUCT, null, contentValues);
    Log.e("DATABASE OPERATIONS", "One row inserted...");

}

public Cursor getProduct(String product_code, SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)
{


    String[] projections = {ProductContract.NewProductInfo.PRODUCT_PLACE};
    String selection = ProductContract.NewProductInfo.PRODUCT_CODE+" LIKE ? ";
    String[] selection_args = {product_code};
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(ProductContract.NewProductInfo.TABLE_PRODUCT, projections, selection, selection_args, null, null, null);
    return cursor;


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)

{

}
```

thank you